# Wired Connection suddenly not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

This computer is used to serve SSH remote access.
The ethernet cable and network are all working fine.
However, the computer has suddenly lost connection and now shows '?' sign for the wired connection.
I pinged all the sites but got 100% loss - obviously bc of the connection issue

I already tried `sudo nmcli networking on`, `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but none of those made a change.

Here are the few details below:

`ifconfig`

```
docker 0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:20ff:fe94:d4fc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:a5:52:87:d7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 141 bytes 16811 (16.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 165.132.40.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 165.132.40.255
    ether f0:2f:74:b2:71:5a  txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
    RX packets 18768  bytes 1132857 (1.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8204  bytes 382369 (382.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 26355  bytes 2164297(2.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 26355  bytes 2164297 (2.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth28a687f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNfe80NING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::408a:fff:fe6f:29f0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 42:8a:0f:6f:29:f0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 216  bytes 26045 (26.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`nmcli device status`

```
enp10s0      ethernet  connected  profile 1
docker0      bridge    connected  docker0
veth28a687f  ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo           loopback  unmanaged  --
```